# Как найти все комбинации выбора данной суммы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, комбинаторика

Дана сумма, например 25, и даны числа, например 2, 5, 10
Нужно найти все комбинации выбора данной суммы.
То есть программа должна вывести 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5, 5 + 5 + 5 + 10, 5 + 10 + 10, 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 10 + 5 и тд.

Какими алгоритмами / методами / библиотеками посоветуете воспользоваться?

Comment: Для начала попробуйте поискать - вдруг такой вопрос уже был...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитай задачи о рюкзаковании, вот подробная статья, например https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=815&chapterid=60

Comment: *“Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.”*

Comment: Это другая задача

Answer (score 0):

требуется алгоритм? возьмите за основу что-нибудь типа этого:

```
функция поиск (сумма, допустимые_слагаемые, список_слагаемых) {
  если сумма = 0, то {
    напечатать список_слагаемых
    возврат
  }
  если допустимые_слагаемые = пусто, то возврат
  слагаемое := первый_элемент_списка (допустимые_слагаемые)
  допустимые_слагаемые := убрать_первый_элемент_списка (допустимые_слагаемые)
  для количество_слагаемых от 0 до сумма / слагаемое {
    вызов функции поиск (сумма, допустимые_слагаемые, список_слагаемых)
    сумма := сумма - слагаемое
    если сумма < 0 то возврат
    список_слагаемых := добавить_элемент_в_список (список_слагаемых, слагаемое)
  }
}

исходная_сумма := 25
допустимые_слагаемые := 2 5 10
текущий_список_слагаемых := пусто

вызов функции поиск (исходная_сумма, допустимые_слагаемые, текущий_список_слагаемых)
```